# How can i redirect my user and admin to different page

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, passwords

How can i redirect my user and admin to different page, i have try using different online method but not working. i will like if you can help fetch out the errors or faults in my code. thanks

check the code and help me solve the error am getting

am trying to redirect the user after a successful login in to admin or member page. i can only redirect all user to a particular page ("Location: ./admin/index.php"); but cant set the admin user to redirect to admin page

```
        session_start();
    // Change this to your connection info.
    $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DB_USER = 'root';
    $DB_PASS = '';
    $DB_NAME = 'schoolexamdatabase';


    // Try and connect using the info above.
        $con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
        if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
            // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
            die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
// Now we check if the data was submitted, isset will check if the data exists.
if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    die ('Username and/or password does not exist!');
}
// Prepare our SQL 
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->store_result(); 


    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();      
        // Account exists, now we verify the password.
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            // Verification success! User has loggedin!
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

        } else {

                      header ("Location: ./admin/index.php");
        }

    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
}
?>   `
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand.  What are you trying to do? Your code has a couple of misplaced `else`

Comment: am trying to redirect the user after a successful login in to admin or member page header i canonly redirect all user to a particular page ("Location: ./admin/index.php"); but cant choice the admin user to redirect to admin page

Answer (score -1):

```
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
        // Verification success! User has loggedin!
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

    // this else doesn’t belong here
    //} else {

                  header ("Location: ./admin/index.php");
    }
```

**update**

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password, status FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
// Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->store_result(); 


// Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $password, $status);
    $stmt->fetch();      
    // Account exists, now we verify the password.
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
        // Verification success! User has loggedin!
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

    //} else {
if ($status == 1) {

                  header ("Location: ./admin/index.php");
    }

elseif ($status == 2) { header(“location: ./members/index.php”);}
```

Comment: yeah..... it only redirect all users on my database, but am trying to redirect two different users, like the admin to  header ("Location: ./admin/index.php"); and members to header ("Location: ./member/index.php");

Comment: Then you are going to need a little bit more work. You need the database to hold a value of whether this is an admin or a regular user, and then you can write in if statement. If admin set location, if user set location ...

Comment: i create a value called 'status' ................admin has '1' as is value while other members has '2' as their value.

Comment: @Haim can you explain what it is that you did that you thought would have solved their question?

Comment: Hmmm added an extra column to the select query and based on the results of that column if password matches set another location

Comment: what about the else statement at the bottom of the the code that handle echo statement for incorrect password. I have an error after typing the code at the php ending tag ?> which shows the code is not yet complete. plesse check through

Comment: That's because I didn't rewrite your entire code, I just added a piece to it, you need to keep the rest of your code after the if else that I added

Comment: Look in the original code that you posted, you have a ` after the close PHP tag

Comment: Can you help me with the full code... Am a bit lost thanks

Answer (score -1):

Finally got it ...... i remove the if statement for $status and i paste the at the end of the login verification. check my previous code.

PREVIOUS

```
session_start();
    // Change this to your connection info.
    $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DB_USER = 'root';
    $DB_PASS = '';
    $DB_NAME = 'schoolexamdatabase';


    // Try and connect using the info above.
        $con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
        if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
            // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
            die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
// Now we check if the data was submitted, isset will check if the data exists.
if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    die ('Username and/or password does not exist!');
}
// Prepare our SQL 
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->store_result(); 


    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();      
        // Account exists, now we verify the password.
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            // Verification success! User has loggedin!
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

        } else {

                      header ("Location: ./admin/index.php");
        }

    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
}
?>
```

UPDATE: WORK LIKE MAGIC

THANKS TO ALL WHO CONTRIBUTE @ Haim  @Funk Forty Niner

Thank You guys

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // Change this to your connection info.
    $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DB_USER = 'root';
    $DB_PASS = '';
    $DB_NAME = 'schoolexamdatabase';


    // Try and connect using the info above.
    $con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
    if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
        die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }


    // Now we check if the data was submitted, isset will check if the data exists.
    if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
        // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
        die ('Username and/or password does not exist!');
    }


    // Prepare our SQL 
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password, status FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->store_result(); 


    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password, $status);
        $stmt->fetch();      
        // Account exists, now we verify the password.
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            // Verification success! User has loggedin!
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;




                //echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '!';
            } else {
                echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
        }
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        echo 'Could not prepare statement!';
    }
    if ($status == 1) {

                      header ('Location: ./admin/index.php');
        }

    elseif ($status == 2) { 


            header('location: ./members/index.php');
    }
    ?>
```